# AKS Container failed to start

Tags: dockerfile, azure-aks

I updated my docker file to upgrade ubuntu but it started failing and I'm unsure why...

dockerfile:

```
# using digest for version 20.04 as there is multiple digest that used this tag#
FROM ubuntu@sha256:82becede498899ec668628e7cb0ad87b6e1c371cb8a1e597d83a47fac21d6af3

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN echo "APT::Get::Assume-Yes \"true\";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90assumeyes

#install tools
#removed for clarity

WORKDIR /azp

COPY ./start.sh .

RUN chmod +x start.sh

CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

my evens from the pod

```
Successfully assigned se-agents/agent-se-linux-5c9f647768-25p7v to aks-linag-56790600-vmss000002
Pulling image "compregistrynp.azurecr.io/agent-se-linux:25319"
Successfully pulled image "comregistrynp.azurecr.io/agent-se-linux:25319"
Created container agent-se-linux
Started container agent-se-linux
Back-off restarting failed container
```

When I check the error in the pod, I see the following message:

```
standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory
```

Not even sure where to look anymore. The only difference in the dockerfile was the ubuntu tag and I added 1 tool to install. I tried to deploy what was in Prod to dev and it's failing with the same error. I'm convinced there's something in my AKS...

Comment: do you happen to be on windows? it could be the line endings when you edited the file as mentioned in [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/433444/cant-run-script-file-in-docker-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: This was the exact issue.. when I deploy to my AKS, I'm going to put a task that will convert the shell script to Linux to avoid this problem in the future

Comment: glad it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that someone on my team had modified the shell script and didn't set the proper End of Line characters to Lf.

I will be running a script to convert the file to Linux to ensure this doesn't happen again in my pipeline!